# Message box to filter data

Tags: vba

I have 3 columns, Float, Relative Volume and RSI. And I am using the following code to delete the active cells that did not meet the given conditions. For example, delete the relative volume below 5, delete the RSI above 10, and delete all the floats that are above 10 million.

For example, this is the code for RSI Relative volume...

```
   n = 2
Cells(n, 10).Select
Do While ActiveCell <> ""
Cells(n, 10).Select
If Trim(ActiveCell) < 5 Then
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
Else
n = n + 1
End If
Cells(n, 10).Select
Loop
Cells(n, 10).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
```

I need to change the 5 (the condition)...

I am trying to define a message box, that ask me for the thee parameters, when I begin to run the macro, so I don't have to change them in the code...

Like this:

Stock Market

Float:
Relative:
RSI:

Can someboy please help me .... Thank you in advance...

Comment: Your code won't delete anything, at least not anything you claim that it would. Giving better instruction to it won't help. Your way to progress is to first delete one item. From that central piece you can work backward to write code to qualify an item for deletion based on your criteria, sideways, to call your code in a loop, and forward, entering the qualifying criteria by InputBox (not MessgeBox). Quite likely, you will prefer a small user form in place of 3 InputBoxes. But that isn't a task for the very near future.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is three Inputboxes (all explaned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/user-interface-help/inputbox-function)):

```
FloatValue = InputBox("Float Value:", "Set FLoat Value...")
RelativeValue = InputBox("Relative Value:", "Set Relative Value...")
RSIValue = InputBox("RSI Value:", "Set RSI Value...")
```

Of course the variables need declaration for the right type...

After this you need to change your code to use the variables created (e.g. FloatValue, RelativeValue ...) instead of hardwired values.

So if I understand your code well, then instead of this:

```
If Trim(ActiveCell) < 5 Then
```

You would have that (as this is your RSI):

```
If Trim(ActiveCell) < RSIValue
```

I am just realising, some of this has already been pointed out by @Variatus.